# Chuwi Hi10 Pro silead touchscreen

Tags: touchscreen

The driver and firmware is working in that the screen responds to my finger but, the coordinates are no-where near correct. 
I tried xinput --map-to-output silead_ts DSI-1. When using xcal and touch the targets, all the adjustment points tend to group on the left (towards bottom) side of the screen. The tablet is docked to keyboard in landscape mode (rotated right). I also tried it in all screen orientations.
The matrix that xcal produces (in landscape) is roughly
[[0 -2 2]
[-3 0 1]
[0 0 1]]
The model is CWI529, HQ64G42161206XXX
I used the hi10_pro-z8350 firmware https://github.com/onitake/gsl-firmware/tree/master/firmware/chuwi/hi10_pro-z8350
The X Y coordinates could be inverted but, don't know how to fix (flip).
I had it working in Manjaro Arch but not working in Ubuntu 18.10
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Solved issue
this script works, changed "DSI1" to "DSI-1" and it seems to wok best when not using Wayland: https://github.com/danielotero/linux-on-hi10/blob/master/touchscreen/rotation